# WordPress WooCommerce emails preview

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to style WordPress WooCommerce emails, but except for the "default" template I cannot find a preview button...
I can't create an order every time that I'll change something, do you know any way to preview all the different types of emails? like customer-completed-order or customer-invoice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a solution here:
http://enru.co.uk/2014/02/17/testing-woocommerce-emails/

In case someone else has the same issue, this works great.

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to your own question, then mark it completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here:
http://enru.co.uk/2014/02/17/testing-woocommerce-emails/

In case someone else has the same issue, this works great.